# Filter out pandas dataframe based on two attribute combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas Dataframe, in which I have examples of soccer games. There are two attributes `home_team_name` and `away_team_name`. Teams play each other twice, in the first leg one team is home and other away, then the situation is reversed. One team name can appear many times in the data set as away or home team, but only twice(once home and once away) in combination with one specific team. I want to split the data in two parts.

```
1498744800,Jun 29 2017 - 2:00pm,complete,8000,Irtysh,Dunav 2010
1498747500,Jun 29 2017 - 2:45pm,complete,15000,Kairat,Atlantas
1499360400,Jul 6 2017 - 5:00pm,complete,5100,Dunav 2010,Irtysh
1499356800,Jul 6 2017 - 4:00pm,complete,1450,Atlantas,Kairat
```

Example from the .csv file that used to create the dataframe. I want the first example in one part and the second in the second part. The examples are not next to each other in the real .csv, this is just to illustrate what I want. In the example from the .csv the first and second row would go into the first part and the third and fourth in the second.

In the first part there will be the games of the first leg.

In the second part there should be return legs of these games. So the ones in which home_team_name is the away_team_name from the first leg and the away_team_name is the home_team_name from the first leg.

Feel free to ask for a better explanation.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Every game is a home game for one team and away for the other. How do you decide how to split what? I'd understand if you wanted to have 1 group per team, but 1 group for home and away is nonsense. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: There are pairs of matches. So two matches played by the same two teams. In the second game their role as home or away team is reversed. I want the first games of this pairs and the second games of this pairs.

Comment: Yeah, but in the first game, the role is reversed for the other team... right?

Comment: Yes. There are many pairs like this.

Comment: I changed the example from the .csv for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort values by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and create boolean mask by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for invert boolean mask:

```
m = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['home_team_name','away_team_name']], axis=1), index=df.index)
       .duplicated(keep='last'))
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
           id                  date     state    val home_team_name  \
0  1498744800  Jun 29 2017 - 2:00pm  complete   8000         Irtysh   
1  1498747500  Jun 29 2017 - 2:45pm  complete  15000         Kairat   

  away_team_name  
0     Dunav 2010  
1       Atlantas

df2 = df[~m]
print (df2)
           id                 date     state   val home_team_name  \
2  1499360400  Jul 6 2017 - 5:00pm  complete  5100     Dunav 2010   
3  1499356800  Jul 6 2017 - 4:00pm  complete  1450       Atlantas   

  away_team_name  
2         Irtysh  
3         Kairat
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['home_team_name','away_team_name']], axis=1), index=df.index))
            0       1
0  Dunav 2010  Irtysh
1    Atlantas  Kairat
2  Dunav 2010  Irtysh
3    Atlantas  Kairat
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of an unorthodox way to do this. It involves assembling a new column `mash` which is the same for each member of the pair. Then grouping by this column and selecting the first and last halves/legs:

```
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""id,date,done,attendance,home,away
1498744800,Jun 29 2017 - 2:00pm,complete,8000,Irtysh,Dunav 2010
1498747500,Jun 29 2017 - 2:45pm,complete,15000,Kairat,Atlantas
1499360400,Jul 6 2017 - 5:00pm,complete,5100,Dunav 2010,Irtysh
1499356800,Jul 6 2017 - 4:00pm,complete,1450,Atlantas,Kairat
1498744800,July 23 2017 - 2:00pm,complete,8000,Arsenal,Chelsea
1498747500,July 26 2017 - 2:45pm,complete,15000,Wolves,Liverpool
1499360400,Jul 28 2017 - 5:00pm,complete,5100,Liverpool,Wolves
1499356800,Aug 3 2017 - 4:00pm,complete,1450,Chelsea,Arsenal"""), sep=",")
df['mash'] = df.home + df.away
df.mash = df.mash.apply(sorted)
df.mash = df.mash.str.join("")
df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df = df.sort_values('date')
first_leg_df = df.groupby('mash').first().reset_index(drop=True)
second_leg_df = df.groupby('mash').last().reset_index(drop=True)
```

First Leg Result:

```
           id                date      done  attendance     home        away
0  1498744800 2017-06-29 14:00:00  complete        8000   Irtysh  Dunav 2010
1  1498744800 2017-07-23 14:00:00  complete        8000  Arsenal     Chelsea
2  1498747500 2017-06-29 14:45:00  complete       15000   Kairat    Atlantas
3  1498747500 2017-07-26 14:45:00  complete       15000   Wolves   Liverpool
```

Second Leg Result:

```
           id                date      done  attendance        home     away
0  1499360400 2017-07-06 17:00:00  complete        5100  Dunav 2010   Irtysh
1  1499356800 2017-08-03 16:00:00  complete        1450     Chelsea  Arsenal
2  1499356800 2017-07-06 16:00:00  complete        1450    Atlantas   Kairat
3  1499360400 2017-07-28 17:00:00  complete        5100   Liverpool   Wolves
```